# Merge link and select params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my case i have link with params and select with params

If I filter `@posts` with select `(:per_page)` and then with `(:pub)` params everything is ok, because I used `params.merge` in link.

But now if I want to use first link and then select, it does not work, because I don't know where I should write `params.merge` in my select.

Code from my controller:

```
 def index
    @posts = Post
    @posts = @posts.published unless params[:pub]
    @posts = @posts.where(:published => params[:pub]) if params[:pub]
    @posts = @posts.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page] || 5)
  end
```

code from view

```
<%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select(%w(1 2 3), params[:per_page].to_i), :onchange => "if(this.value){window.location='?per_page='+this.value;}" %>

<%= link_to "unpubl", params.merge(:pub => :f) %>
<%= link_to "publ", params.merge(:pub => :t) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are trying to create some kind of HTML filters to pass to your controller right ?

If this is the case, you should build your HTML filters using a `form`. This way you would not have to deal with "merging" your options into the `params` hash. The form will take care of that for you.

Example:

```
<%= form_tag posts_path, method: :get %>
  <%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select(%w(1 2 3), params[:per_page].to_i) %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'published', 'true' %>

  <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller:

```
params[:published]
params[:per_page]
```

will hold the corresponding values.

More information about `form_tag` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html)

Comment: good suggestion
but when im trying to do this, i have an syntax_error
`syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: There's a missing quote on the check_box_tag line. That's why you get the syntax error.

Comment: i saw it and write 
`<%= check_box_tag 'published', 'true' %>`

but it's still syntax_error

Comment: What lines does it tells you ?

Comment: `<%= form_tag posts_path do %>` it's correct, 

but another error in select `wrong number of arguments (2 for 3..5)`

Comment: after i cnange select or checkboxes form do nothing

Comment: you need a button to submit it, or you must use javascript to submit it.

Comment: done `<%= submit_tag(value = "Save changes", options = {})  %>`
 when i submit form it's redirect me to `posts/n+1`

Comment: submiting form trying to create new posts

Comment: what is right way to write submit button which will be redirect to link with selected params?

Comment: it works with this code, but here is one new problem, when i choose 2 checkbox work only last, it's mean `published=t&published=f` returns only `posts`  with `:published => false`

Comment: Don't use 2 checkboxes... the value will change if you click on it.

Comment: yep, you right, i should block another checkbox if one selected, or use radiobutton